# Populate VBA Array with variable values

Tags: vba

sorry I haven’t found the way to solve this issue. When trying to define an array in this way

```
Dim Arr As Variant: Arr = [{"Value1", "Value2"}]
```

works perfectly, but when trying to do the same using variables (i.e.)

```
Dim Arr as variant
v1 = "Value1"
v2 = "Value2"
Arr = [{v1, v2}]
```

will throw a syntax error. Please is there some way to solve it? I do need to use variables to populate the array. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked up how to initialize an array in VBA?

Comment: square brackets in VBA is shorthand for `Application.Evaluate()` which means anything in the square brackets will be treated as **literal** text and evaluated as if it was entered into the formula bar. That's why you cannot use variables - initialise it as a proper `Array` object instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
Arr = [{"Value1", "Value2"}]
```

is

```
Arr = Application.Evaluate("{""Value1"", ""Value2""}")
```

You are making the Excel formula engine to parse the expression, and it parses it as an [array constant](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-array-constants-in-array-formulas-477443ea-5e71-4242-877d-fcae47454eb8).
Obviously the formula engine knows nothing about VBA variables.

You should simply use

```
Arr = Array(v1, v2)
```